# Custom error page with django 2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x

here is my code in urls.py :

```
def handler500(request, exception):
    response =  HttpResponseServerError('error.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

but i have a :

```
TypeError: handler500() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exception'
```

What am i missing ?

edit bis the whole code :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.http import HttpResponseServerError

urlpatterns = [path("admin/", admin.site.urls)]
urlpatterns += [path("", include("Exchange.urls"))]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def handler404(request, exception, template_name='404.html'):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response


def handler500(request,exception):
    response =  HttpResponseServerError('error.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

so here is the whole urls.py file, it seems that my post is mostly code so i have to add more details like the fact this is the django 2.0 version or it runs on python3.6 on a ubuntu os.

Comment: Where you are using this `handler500()` function ?

Comment: in urls.py why ?

Comment: add those code also. I'm asking because the error is raised because  you are calling the `handler500()` in wrong way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view), there it defines the 500 handler with just one positional argument.

Change you code from

```
def handler500(request, exception):
```

to

```
def handler500(request):
```

Let us know if that works.

---

Just a hint: django docs on [customizing error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) suggests placing your view functions in `views.py` and just adding the string name to your `urls.py`, like:

```
# in views.py
def handler500(request):
    ...

# in urls.py
handler500 = 'mysite.views.handler500'
```