# Custom 500 error page does not take the correct number of arguments - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to prepare custom 404 and 500 error pages for a production. The 404 works fine, but I'm not able to run the 500.

In my `urls.py` file:

```
from client_interface.views.errors.server_error_view import ServerErrorView
handler500 = ServerErrorView.as_view()
```

`client_interface/views/errors/server_error_view.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View


class ServerErrorView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "client_interface/errors/500.html")
```

I'm getting `?: (urls.E007) The custom handler500 view 'client_interface.views.errors.server_error_view.ServerErrorView' does not take the correct number of arguments (request).` error all the time.
I tried to change the arguments of the `get` method to `get(request)` but it didn't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639823/custom-error-page-with-django-2-0

Comment: If I understand correctly, this answer suggests leaving only the request argument in the get method, but as I wrote earlier, it does not help in my case (the error remains the same).

Comment: interesting question but `django` itself uses the function based view **FBV** version NOT class based view **CBV** version, just to keep things simple

Comment: If I use **FBV** for error pages, everything works fine, but the rest of the application is using **CBV**, so I would like to be consistent, if it's possible of course.